# why adding a new id column with monotonically increasing id break after 352

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark 2.2.0. To add a new column of incrementing value.  I have used following code:

```
new_df = df.withColumn('Id', monotonically_increasing_id())
```

But it breaks after row number 352 like this:

[image: screenshot of error]

Any option to fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per mic4ael answer the generated ID is only guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but not consecutive. You can generate consecutive and monotonically increasing ids using `row_number`, however, this approach does not scale very well and should be avoided for larger datasets. For example, taking this as the input data:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,row_number
df = spark.createDataFrame([('33004', ''),('33004', ''),('33010', 'Muxia'), ('33020','Fuensanta'),('33020','Fuensanta')], ("Zip", "PostalRegion"))
```

You can add a sequential `ID` column using the following approach:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window().orderBy("PostalRegion")
df = df.select(row_number().over(w).alias("ID"), col("*"))
df.show()
```

This gives as output:

```
+---+-----+------------+
| ID|  Zip|PostalRegion|
+---+-----+------------+
|  1|33004|            |
|  2|33004|            |
|  3|33020|   Fuensanta|
|  4|33020|   Fuensanta|
|  5|33010|       Muxia|
+---+-----+------------+
```

Comment: @Jaci good solution, thanks. How can we modify the code to do the same function, that is add ID numbers incrementally without using the groupBy. I would like to reserve the natural order of the df and not re-order it using "PostalRegion"

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) the values generated by the function don't have to be consecutive.

> The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but not consecutive

Comment: Kind of strange and misleading behavior if you ask me, to count consecutively for so long and then jump like that, though I'm sure there's a good reason for it

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in spark documentation, `monotonically_increasing_id` may not be consecutive. You can convert `dataframe` to `rdd` and use `rdd.zipWithIndex()` instead for adding incremental value.

Comment: That you for your answer.  By adding a block of code that completely solves the problem.  i.e. `new_df = ....`